# How to make other values other than the one I needed to be NaN?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, nan

I am trying to convert RGB value from a png file into dBZ value. I want to make other value other than the one I needed to be NaN. Here is my code:

```
def convert_dbz(image, rgbradar, rgbdbz):
"""
This function for converting RGB color from .png image into dbz value
image : image file with .png or other format
rgbradar : list RGB that are extracted from the image
rgbdbz : list DBZ value from image
"""

im = np.empty((image.shape[0],image.shape[1]))  
k = 0
while k < 13:
    for i in range (image.shape[0]):
         for j in range (image.shape[1]):
                if (image[i,j,:] == rgbradar[k]).all() == True:
                    im[i,j] = rgbdbz[k]
                else:
                    image[i,j,:] = np.nan
    k+1
return im
```

And here are the parameters:

```
rgbradar = [[250,206,4],[255,79,0],[129,128,0],[3,228,1],[3,177,0],[1,204,129],[1,226,255],
         [4,160,255],[5,58,253],[2,0,224],[1,0,176],[133,0,206],[254,0,199]]
rgbdbz = [5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55,60,65]
```

When I ran the code I got the error:

```
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_28740/3803417785.py in convert_dbz(image, rgbradar, rgbdbz)
     14                         im[i,j] = rgbdbz[k]
     15                     else:
---> 16                         image[i,j,:] = np.nan
     17         k+1
     18     return im

ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

I don't really understand the error because I was trying to convert the value to NaN not the other way around.

Is the code I write wrong from the beginning?

Comment: what is the `type` of the variable `image`?

Comment: hi there, the type of variable `image` is `uint8` because the image is being read using OpenCV

Answer (score 0):

I think the variable `image` is of type `np.int` and `np.nan` is of type `np.float`, hence it fails to assign the value. You may want to use `image[i,j,:] = None` instead or change the `dtype` of `image` to `np.float`.